# Why does Java's InflaterInputStream (and other similar classes) only conditionally call end on it's internal Inflater

Tags: java, memory, native, heap-memory

In Java 8 the `close()` method for `InflaterInputStream` is as shown below

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    if (!closed) {
        if (usesDefaultInflater)
            inf.end();
        in.close();
        closed = true;
    }
}
```

`usesDefaultInflater` is a boolean that is only `true` if the constructor below is used

```
public InflaterInputStream(InputStream in) {
    this(in, new Inflater());
    usesDefaultInflater = true;
}
```

Any other constructor such as this one below results in this boolean being set to false

```
new InflaterInputStream(decryptInputStream, new Inflater(), 4096);
```

As a result, unless you use the default constructor the `end()` method is not called on the `Inflater` and this means unnecessary native memory consumption until the `finalize` method is called on the `Inflater` by the Finalizer thread potentially a long time after the `InflaterInputStream` is closed. See the implementation in `Inflater` below.

```
/**
 * Closes the decompressor and discards any unprocessed input.
 * This method should be called when the decompressor is no longer
 * being used, but will also be called automatically by the finalize()
 * method. Once this method is called, the behavior of the Inflater
 * object is undefined.
 */
public void end() {
    synchronized (zsRef) {
        long addr = zsRef.address();
        zsRef.clear();
        if (addr != 0) {
            end(addr);
            buf = null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Closes the decompressor when garbage is collected.
 */
protected void finalize() {
    end();
}
```

To get around this you need to override the `close` method on the `InflaterInputStream` like so

```
new InflaterInputStream(decryptInputStream, new Inflater(), 4096) {    
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            super.close();
        } finally {
            inf.end();
        }
    }
}
```

This is easily missed and it seems to me like it might have been sensible to call `end()` by default and allow the user to override that behaviour by providing a constructor where you could specify `false`, or at the very least a constructor that uses the default `Inflater` but that also allows you to set the buffer size.

Anyway, I'm guessing there's some logical reason that it's designed the way it is and I've just failed to grok it.  Hoping someone can enlighten me...

This also applies to `DeflaterInputStream`, `DeflaterOutputStream`, and `InflaterOutputStream` amongst others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many methods in the Java Runtime Library that takes e.g. an [`OutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) (such as [`Files.copy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.io.OutputStream-)). Unless those methods *explicitly* state that the stream will be closed by the method, the stream will not be closed. Closing the stream is the responsibility of the stream "owner", e.g. the caller of the method.

Similarly, neither constructor of [`InflaterInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/InflaterInputStream.html#constructor.summary) that takes an [`Inflater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) states that they will [`end()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html#end--) the `Inflater`, which means that they won't. It is up to the caller to end it, when needed.

When using the constructor that creates the `Inflater` for you, the `InflaterInputStream` becomes the "owner" of that *internal* `Inflater`, and it is therefore the responsibility of the `InflaterInputStream` to end the `Inflater`.

#### Resource Management

The general guideline for resource management is that, unless otherwise documented, whoever allocates a resource is responsible for releasing (closing, ending, ...) the resource.

`Inflater` is a resource, so normal resource management rules apply.

Comment: yeah you're right, I think it might have been useful to provide a constructor that just took an `InputStream` and an `int` for the buffer size without requiring the `Inflater` to be passed in also, that way you don't have to create an instance in the constructor with `new` just to set a custom buffer size and then have to also override the `close()` method just to avoid unnecessary native memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

As with many "why" questions, this is an educated guess. I didn't see any explicit explanation for this, so who knows what the original programmer was thinking? Anyway, take my answer with a grain of salt.

The other constructors all take an `Inflater` instance, which means that the user has a reference to the (internal) `Inflater`. Note that these classes have no getter to get the `Inflater` out. So the only way the user would have a reference to it, is by passing it from outside (well, that and using reflection, but let's not go there).

So perhaps the assumption was that since the user passed his own `Inflater` instance, then he wants to manage the `Inflater` himself, possibly reusing it after this steam has ended. Thus, closing the `Inflater` when the stream is closed isn't a good idea.

Comment: This makes sense to me, it would be surprising to have the `Inflater` closed when the stream is closed if you intended to hold onto it for some reason.

Comment: It's still an odd behavior. Especially since it doesn't look like it's documented anywhere.

Comment: @Malt No odd behavior, and it *is* implicitly documented, by the lack of text saying anything. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57516136/5221149).

Comment: I guess "odd" is a matter of perspective. This behavior is neither ergonomic nor intuitive. So I find it odd someone chose to implement it this way, even if I can kinda understand what that person was going for.